# Polymorphic relation returning 0 in blade template, but normal on json output

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get all posts that have reports and then eager load the reports.

**Relations**

```
//Post.php

public function reports()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Report', 'reportable');
}

//Report.php

public function reportable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Reports Controller**

```
public function postReportsIndex()
{
    $posts = Post::whereHas('reports')
                    ->with('reports.creator', 'comments')
                    ->latest()
                    ->paginate();

    //return view('channels.reports.post-reports', compact('posts'));

    return $posts;
 }
```

**JSON Output**

When I `return $post;` and get the JSON output everything works fine and the posts `reports: []` are all there.

```
{  
    "current_page":1,
    "data":[  
        {  
           "id":101,
           "user_id":1,
           "title":"GREATEST SKATEBOARDING TRICKS EVER 2018! #1 BEST SKATE & SKATEBOARD & SKATING TRICKS COMPILATION",
           "content":"GREATEST SKATEBOARDING TRICKS EVER 2018! #1 BEST SKATE & SKATEBOARD & SKATING TRICKS COMPILATION. Skateboarding is one of the most popular types of extreme s...",
           "created_at":"2018-09-02 22:14:27",
           "updated_at":"2018-09-22 06:38:26",
           "reports":[  
                {  
                    "id":1,
                    "user_id":1,
                    "content":"Broke rule 1",
                    "reportable_id":101,
                    "reportable_type":"App\\Post",
                    "reportable_created_at":"2018-11-29 20:27:56",
                    "created_at":"2018-11-29 20:27:47",
                    "updated_at":null,
                    "creator":{  
                        "id":1,
                        "username":"Frank",
                        "slug":"Frank",
                        "name":"Frank Lettuce",
                        "email":"frank@example.com",
                        "created_at":"2018-09-02 22:12:31",
                        "updated_at":"2018-09-25 00:24:59",
                    }
                },
                {  
                    "id":4,
                    "user_id":1,
                    "content":"Broke rule 1",
                    "reportable_id":101,
                    "reportable_type":"App\\Post",
                    "reportable_created_at":"2018-11-29 20:27:56",
                    "created_at":"2018-11-29 20:27:47",
                    "updated_at":null,
                    "creator":{  
                        "id":1,
                        "username":"Frank",
                        "slug":"Frank",
                        "name":"Frank Lettuce",
                        "email":"frank@example.com",
                        "created_at":"2018-09-02 22:12:31",
                        "updated_at":"2018-09-25 00:24:59",
                    }
                }
            ],
           "comments":[  
                {  
                    "id":1,
                    "content":"Godfather ipsum dolor sit amet. Only don't tell me you're innocent. Because it insults my intelligence and makes me very angry. If anything in this life is certain, if history has taught us anything, it is that you can kill anyone. Don't ever give an order like that again. Not while I'm alive. I want your answer and the money by noon tomorrow. And one more thing. Don't you contact me again, ever. From now on, you deal with Turnbull. I have a sentimental weakness for my children and I spoil them, as you can see. They talk when they should listen.",
                    "post_id":101,
                    "user_id":1,
                    "created_at":"2018-09-02 22:15:57",
                    "updated_at":"2018-09-02 22:15:57",
                    "post":{  
                        "id":101,
                        "user_id":1,
                        "title":"GREATEST SKATEBOARDING TRICKS EVER 2018! #1 BEST SKATE & SKATEBOARD & SKATING TRICKS COMPILATION",
                        "slug":"greatest-skateboarding-tricks-ever-2018-1-best-skate-skateboard-skating-tricks-compilation",
                        "content":"GREATEST SKATEBOARDING TRICKS EVER 2018! #1 BEST SKATE & SKATEBOARD & SKATING TRICKS COMPILATION. Skateboarding is one of the most popular types of extreme s...",
                        "created_at":"2018-09-02 22:14:27",
                        "updated_at":"2018-09-22 06:38:26",
                    }
                }
           ]
        }
    ],
    "first_page_url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-reports?page=1",
    "from":1,
    "last_page":1,
    "last_page_url":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-reports?page=1",
    "next_page_url":null,
    "path":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-reports",
    "per_page":15,
    "prev_page_url":null,
    "to":1,
    "total":1
}
```

**Blade Template**

```
<h1>Reports For Posts</h1>
<hr>
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h4><a href=" forums/{{$post->slug}} ">{{ $post->title }}</a></h4>
            <span class="social-share-title pull-left text-capitalize">
                By <a href="#">{{ $post->creator->username }}</a> 
                {{$post->created_at->format('F d, Y') }}
            </span>
            </br></br>
            <ul>
                {{$post->reports}}
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

**Problem**

For some reason when I try and use blade to get the post reports all I get on the screen is a "0"

[image]

When I try looping through the reports I get an error:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($post->reports as $report)
        <li>
            {{ $report->content }} <i> By {{ $report->user }}</i>
            <p>{{$report->created_at}}</p>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community/resources/views/channels/reports/post-reports.blade.php)

Comment: What output do you expect of `{{$post->reports}}`?

Comment: It should output a JSON response of all of the reports. It's just me testing to see if it works. For my comment model, which also has a polymorphic relation it works as expected. I also have a sandbox where this code is also working.

Comment: What's the result of `{{ dd($post->reports) }}`?

Comment: The result is: `0`

Comment: What's the result of `{{ dd($post->getRelations()) }}`?

Comment: `array:3 [▼
  "reports" => Collection {#393 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => Report {#465 ▶}
      1 => Report {#464 ▶}
    ]
  }
  "comments" => Collection {#452 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => Comment {#431 ▶}
    ]
  }
  "creator" => User {#507 ▶}
]`

Comment: Does your `Post` model have a `getReportsAttribute()` method?

Comment: there's no `getReportsAttribute()` method in the post model

Comment: Please post the whole `Post` model.

Comment: `attributes: array:10 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "user_id" => 1
  "content" => "Broke rule 1"
  "reportable_id" => 101
  "reportable_type" => "App\Post"
  "reportable_created_at" => "2018-11-29 20:27:56"
  "created_at" => "2018-11-29 20:27:47"
  "updated_at" => null
]`

Here's the attributes reports

Comment: I meant the `Post` class.

Comment: Is there anyway I can send it to you privately?

Comment: We can try it without the code. Are there any "special" methods in the model? Are you overriding any parent methods?

Comment: To check I just got rid of all methods that didn't pertain to the reports query in the Post model. I didn't eliminate any of the Post models relationships though. Samething.

Comment: Does `{{ $post->reports()->get() }}` work?

Comment: >Call to a member function get() on integer (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community/resources/views/channels/reports/post-reports.blade.php)

Comment: Did you try `{{ $post->reports()->get() }}` or `{{ $post->reports->get() }}`?

Comment: Ahh I got that wrong. Sorry I did this: `{{ $post->reports->get() }}` this works and gets all of the reports `{{ $post->reports()->get() }}`

Comment: The `posts` table doesn't have a `reports` column, does it? Does the `Post` model use any traits?

Comment: That's the problem right there. Other dev didn't put reports_count. Thanks for your help. That should solve it.